# How to get the exact font in this document?

Tags: fonts

#### What I'd like to get

[image: Demo of font I want]

#### What I currently get using Latin Modern

[image: What I currently get using latin modern and pdfrender]

#### Comments

Especially, look at the italic font. I really like that italic font even though it looks old. I have tried a lot of fonts available in LaTeX from this [site](https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html). But none of them are exactly this.

Comment: Welcome! Can you give a reference for the book you are talking about?

Comment: Hopefully it's not against the rules since the pdf is available for free: http://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/1962/no306pp01-08.pdf

Comment: I'm afraid you're out of luck. The font is some version of Monotype Modern, which Knuth derived Computer Modern from. There's no port to LaTeX of that fonts available.

Comment: Looking at ‘Properties’ with Acrobat Reader, they're Arial MT and TimesNewRomanPSMT. Try with `newtx`, based on `TeXGyre Termes`, a Times clone.

Comment: @Teepeemm many thanks for the link. It helps me track down the font at least. egreg I thought something like that as well because the fonts in latex font catalog site do not cover this font. 
Bernard I will try it. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @egreg Although [it is available in OpenType.](https://www.linotype.com/172546/monotype-modern-mt-condensed-italic-product.html)

Comment: Davislor, I like the font you linked. I will try it! Many thanks mate

Comment: @Bernard the Properties in Acrobat Reader will be misleading—the text is scanned and the fonts are the ones used for the OCR text layer. If you zoom in on the text, you'll be able to see the bitmaps clearly.